# I get a gap while transition in between sliders? [Design Like Carousel Bootstrap]

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, transition

Recently I am trying to design like bootstrap carousel for Angular developing purpose.
The problem that I head it was the transition itself
as we know left arrow will keep sliding (from right to left) even if we return back to the first item. So I was wondering about how they did it with a perfect transition!
Note that they use display block for the other slides so I did a simple trick with javascript to escape display none render problem.
Finaly I do not know if it is caused the problem or some thing else because I did it as they do but I have a problem that my carousel is making a gap while transiting.
Any ideas about how to fix this?
Here is the code
Run the code and try to press next picture and see the gap between the slides.
[image: See the image]

```js
"use strict";
(function (window) {
    function carousel(selector) {
        if (!(this instanceof carousel)) return new carousel(selector);

        if (selector.nodeType == 1 || selector == window.document || selector == window) {
            this.push(selector);
            return;
        }
        var arr = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        arr.forEach(function (ele) {
            this.push(ele);
        }.bind(this))
        return;
    }
    window.carousel = carousel;
    return;
})(window);

var fn = carousel.prototype = [];
fn.default = {
    "delay": 6000,
    "transition": 'slide',
    "startCycle": true,
    "showArrows": true
};
fn.extend = function (prop) {
    if (prop && typeof prop == "object") {
        for (var value in prop) {
            if (prop.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
                this.default[value] = prop[value];
            }
        }
    }
    return;
};
fn.currPos = 0;
fn.oldPos = 0;
fn.render = function () {
    // this.carouselInner.style.left = -1*this.currPos*this.carouselWidth+'px';

    this.indicators[this.oldPos].classList.remove('active');
    this.indicators[this.currPos].classList.add('active');


    ['prev', 'active'].forEach(function (e, i) {

        (i == 0) ? this.items[this.oldPos].classList.add(e) : this.items[this.oldPos].classList.remove(e);
    }.bind(this));
    // this.items[this.oldPos].classList.add('prev')
    // this.items[this.oldPos].classList.remove('active')
    this.items[this.currPos].classList.add('next')
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        this.items[this.currPos].classList.add('active')
    }.bind(this), 0.001);

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        this.items[this.oldPos].classList.remove('active')
        this.items[this.oldPos].classList.remove('prev')
        this.items[this.currPos].classList.remove('next')
    }.bind(this), 600)
    return;
}
fn.cycle = false;
fn.loop = null;
fn.iteration = window.setInterval.bind(window);
fn.clearIteration = window.clearInterval.bind(window);
fn.stopIteration = function () {
    if (this.cycle && this.loop != null) {
        this.clearIteration(this.loop);
        this.cycle = false;
        this.loop = null;
        this.timeLine.classList.remove('animate');
    }
    return;
}
fn.startIteration = function () {
    if (!this.cycle && this.loop == null) {
        this.timeLine.classList.add('animate');
        this.cycle = true;
        this.loop = this.iteration(function () {
            this.to();
        }.bind(this), this.default.delay);
    }
    return;
}
fn.to = function () {
    this.nextSlide();
    this.timeLine.classList.remove('animate');
    this.timeLine.classList.add('animate');
    return;
};
fn.calculatePosition = function (number) {
    this.oldPos = this.currPos;
    this.currPos = number;
    if (this.currPos != this.oldPos) {
        if (this.currPos > this.itemsLength - 1) {
            this.currPos = 0;
        } else if (this.currPos < 0) {
            this.currPos = this.itemsLength - 1;
        }
        this.render();
    };
    return;
}
fn.events = function () {
    this.next.onclick = function () {
        this.calculatePosition(this.currPos + 1);
    }.bind(this);
    this.prev.onclick = function () {
        this.calculatePosition(this.currPos - 1);
    }.bind(this);
    this.indicators.forEach(function (ele, i) {
        ele.onclick = function () {
            this.calculatePosition(i);
        }.bind(this);
    }.bind(this));
    // window.onresize = function(){
    //  this.arrangeSlides();
    //  this.render();
    // }.bind(this);
    if (this.default.startCycle == true) {
        this[0].addEventListener('mouseenter', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.stopIteration();
        }.bind(this), false);

        this[0].addEventListener('mouseleave', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.startIteration();
        }.bind(this), false);
    };
    return;
}
fn.arrangeSlides = function () {
    this.carouselWidth = this[0].offsetWidth;
    this.items.forEach(function (ele, i) {
        ele.style.left = i * this.carouselWidth + 'px';
    }.bind(this));
    return;
}
fn.cashing = function () {
    this.itemsLength = this[0].querySelectorAll('.carousel-inner .item').length;
    this.next = this[0].querySelectorAll('.carousel-control.right')[0];
    this.prev = this[0].querySelectorAll('.carousel-control.left')[0];
    this.indicators = this[0].querySelectorAll('.carousel-indicators > li');
    this.carouselWidth = this[0].offsetWidth;
    this.carouselInner = this[0].querySelector('.carousel-inner');
    this.items = this[0].querySelectorAll('.carousel-inner .item');
    this.nextSlide = this.next.click.bind(this.next);
    this.prevSlide = this.prev.click.bind(this.prev);
    return;
}
fn.addTimeLine = function () {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'timeLine animate';
    this[0].appendChild(div);
    this.timeLine = div;
    this.timeLine.style.animationDuration = (this.default.delay / 1000) + 's';
    return;
};
fn.init = function (prop) {
    this.cashing();
    this.extend(prop);
    // this.arrangeSlides();
    this.events();
    if (this.default.startCycle == true) {
        this.addTimeLine();
        this.startIteration();
    }
    if (this.default.showArrows == false) {
        this.next.style.display = 'none';
        this.prev.style.display = 'none';
    }
    return this;
}
fn.apply = function (prop) {
    var self = [];
    this.forEach(function (ele) {
        self.push(new carousel(ele).init(prop));
    }.bind(this))
    return {
        "carouselElement": self[0][0],
        "next": self[0].nextSlide,
        "prev": self[0].prevSlide,
        "Indicators": self[0].indicators,
        "Settings": self[0].default
    };
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', arguments.calee);
    carousel('.carousel').apply({
        "delay": '1000',
        "startCycle": false,
        "showArrows": true
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    border-size: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #999;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px;
    background: #aaa;
}

.carousel {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel ol {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 25%;
    text-align: center;
}
.carousel ol li {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.carousel ol li:after {
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    transform: scale(0);
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.carousel ol li.active:after {
    transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel .carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: left .6s ease-in-out;
    transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);
    float: left;
    opacity: 1;
    perspective: 1000px;
    display: none;
}
.carousel .carousel-inner .item img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.carousel .carousel-inner .item .carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.carousel .carousel-inner .prev {
    left: -100%;
    display: block;
}
.carousel .carousel-inner .next {
    left: 100%;
    display: block;
}
.carousel .carousel-inner .active {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel a.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 85%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.carousel a.carousel-control span {
    pointer-events: none;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 180px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.carousel a.carousel-control span i {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.carousel a.carousel-control:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), transparent);
}
.carousel a.carousel-control:hover i {
    color: white;
}
.carousel a.carousel-control.right {
    right: 0%;
    left: 85%;
}
.carousel a.carousel-control.right:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35), transparent);
}
.carousel a.carousel-control.right:hover i {
    color: white;
}
.carousel .timeLine {
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    background: red;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 100%;
}
.carousel .animate {
    animation-name: timeLine;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.05, 0.85);
}
@keyframes timeLine {
    0% {
        background: white;
        right: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        background: red;
        right: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">

    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="6"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="7"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">


            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/800/321" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    Hi my name is Ahmed
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/800/421" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/800/5b1" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/800/051" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/800/321" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/800/c31" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/800/9b1" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/800/abc" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry it is the first time to ask here. i get throw problem until i get the post. BTY i made name edit hopping that it is clear right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue successfully. The problem were in my render function which i modified it like this

**Javascript**

```js
fn.render = function(){
 
 this.indicators[this.oldPos].classList.remove('active');
 this.indicators[this.currPos].classList.add('active'); // dont play with this
 
 
 
 this.items[this.oldPos].classList.add('prev');
 this.items[this.currPos].classList.add('next')
 
 window.setTimeout(function(){
  this.items[this.oldPos].classList.remove('active');
  this.items[this.currPos].classList.add('active');
 }.bind(this), 0.1);
 
 window.setTimeout(function(){
  this.items[this.oldPos].classList.remove('prev')
  this.items[this.currPos].classList.remove('next')
  this.underAnimate = true;
 }.bind(this), 600)
 return;
}
```